# How do I debug individual Django tests in vscode?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I added a launch configuration that allows me to run all tests in Django and another that allows me to run the server, both of these work fine.

I am looking for a way to debug an individual file, but using `${file}` in the arguments gives a normal path which django doesn't like.

I want a way to change `${file}` into a python path so that I can debug my tests on a single file.

`python manage.py test --noinput --keepdb python.path.to.my.file`

works in the command line.

The following configuration seems to be almost right:

```
      {   "name": "Test File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "--noinput",
                "--keepdb",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
```

However, when I run this configuration I get an error, 
which I think is because `${file}` turns into

`path/to/my/file` instead of `path.to.my.file`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no translation of file path to dotted name, so you will need to hard-code that in your `launch.json`.

Comment: Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python, but as the author of import itself in Python I can tell you that it's actually hard to do an accurate translation for everyone in all situations (although we could consider doing an 80% good-enough solution).

Comment: Thanks @Brett . I've started up-voting https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/73 .

Answer (score 12):

If you're on a Mac or Linux, the following launch config should work for a single unit test executed by Django:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django Debug Single Test",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "`echo -n ${relativeFileDirname} | tr \/ .`.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
```

This uses the `tr` command to translate `/` into `.` in the relative path.

Comment: Seems the newer version of vscode is not supporting the above command anymore. I used to be able to run the command and debug a single file but now it just doesnt replace the `/` with `.`

Comment: this work for me, python 3.10 django 4.2, vscode 1.82.2, however i often change `"`echo -n` to the python path to the unit test class

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Windows and the git bash, the launch config with tr will also work, but you'll need to quote the variable substitution and quote the double backslashes.

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django Debug Single Test",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "test",
            "`echo -n \"${relativeFileDirname}\" | tr \\\\ .`.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
```

Answer (score 5):

this works for me in windows under wsl ubuntu with your tests.py as the open file :

```
{
    "name": "Test Django",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "python": "${workspaceFolder}/../.venv/bin/python",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
    "args": [
        "test",
        "${relativeFileDirname}"
    ],
    "django": true
},
```

I don't think you need any echo | tr ... fileBasenameNoExtension  etc.

Comment: Thanks! This should now be the accepted answer Albert Rothman :-)

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of vscode, as mentioned in one of the comments, vscode stopped evaluating the command that is used to send into the args (`echo...`).

As a different workaround for now, I used the following, which was a bit easier for me because of how I use manage.py.

My configuration looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Django Debug Single Test",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
        "args": [
            "dtf",
            "${relativeFile}"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
```

Then, in my case, I added some shortcuts to my manage.py to do things like "manage.py run" (instead of runserver), or "manage.py tap" (instead of --test --parallel 3 --keepdb --settings=settings_tests), etc.
So I added another shortcut called "dtf" (debug test file) which then takes the relative file and replacing the value in the argv before actually running the command.
It looks like this:

```
if 'dtf' in sys.argv:
    logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)

    sys.argv.remove('dtf')
    sys.argv.insert(1, 'test')
    f = sys.argv[2].replace('.py', '')
    f = '.'.join(f.split('/')[1:])
    sys.argv[2] = f

    sys.argv.append('--keepdb')
    sys.argv.append('--settings=my_project.settings_tests')
    print(sys.argv)
```

You can look at some of the shortcuts I use in my manage.py file here:
https://gist.github.com/kalsky/0cba3618452238f3b00354a90d2a51e5

Comment: The analogy of this idea works but only if you are preprocessing the args before manage.py calls `execute_from_command_line`. So, if you want to add a custom command to the django admin, this wont technically work since that happens after `execute_from_command_line`